# ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function createAuthUrl()

Tags: php, api, authentication, google-client

I have a problem trying to use google/apiclient

isLoggedIn()): ?> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function createAuthUrl() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Google\app\class\google_auth.php on line 27 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0025141744{main}( )..\index.php:0 20.0979526816GoogleAuth->getAuthUrl( )..\index.php:22

My index:

```
<?php

    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    require_once('app/class/google_auth.php');//Class
    require_once('app/ini.php');

    $googleClient = new Google_Client();
    $auth = new GoogleAuth($googleClient);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php//Verificar Inicio de Sesion
        if (!$auth->isLoggedIn()): 
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $auth->getAuthUrl(); ?>">Inicie Sesion con Google</a>
    <?php//Si no ha iniciado Sesion
        else: 
    ?>
        <a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>
    <?php//Si no ha iniciado Sesion
        endif; 
    ?>  

</body>
</html>
```

& the class GoogleAuth

```
<?php

    class GoogleAuth{

        protected $client;

        public function _constructor(Google_Client $googleClient = null){
            $this->client = $googleClient;

            if ($this->client) {

                $this->client->setClientId('474251646530-tiho0cbf4d15pcb6.apps.googleusercontent.com');
                $this->client->setClientSecret('bMuLusxZW6ohlI3vn');
                $this->client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/Google/index.php');
                $this->client->setScopes('email');

            }
        }

        public function isLoggedIn(){
            return isset($_SESSION['access_token']);

        }

        public function getAuthUrl(){
            return $this->client->createAuthUrl();

        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: do `print_r($this->cliente);` after `$this->cliente = $googleClient;` See if it's retaining `NULL` or if it's assigning the class `Google_Client`

Comment: if `$this->client` is going to be required for use then 1) you shouldn't be allowing the argument of the constructor that give it it's value to be optional and 2) you should be throwing an error in the constructor if `$this->client` isn't the required object

Comment: nothing happend

Comment: @jocednieves do `var_dump($this->client)` instead of `print_r` as [in this example](https://repl.it/EN0i) `print_r` did nothing while `var_dump` actually printed out that it was null

Comment: where? because i put

Comment: public function _constructor(Google_Client $googleClient = null){
   $this->client = $googleClient;
   var_dump($this->client);

Comment: var_dump give me this:
    object(GoogleAuth)[3]
  protected 'client' => null

Comment: @jocednieves and that's your problem. `$googleClient = new Google_Client();` in your main index is null so when you pass it into your class constructor `$this->client` is set to null and that causes your error. now i am wondering where your `Google_Client` class definition is because your include only show `google_auth.php` and you show us that in that file there's only the `GoogleAuth` class. i see no `Google_Client` class

Comment: Google_Client class is a default class from google api client

Comment: ahhh shit i knew i should have listened to my nagging twitch. your constructor isn't named correctly. it's [`__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) not `_constructor`, your missing an underscore and you've misspelled it as such when you create your class instance it's not calling your constructor. if you want to call `_constructor` you have to do `$auth->_constructor($googleClient)`

Comment: of courseeeeee! Wow thanks, now it work!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is this line of code:

```
$googleCliente = new Google_Client();
```

Change it to:

```
$googleClient = new Google_Client();
```

It's a very basic typo. You are calling it like this:

```
$auth = new GoogleAuth($googleClient); // notice the variable googleClient does not have an e on the end
```

Be sure to proof read your code.